# Adding current class to div on link click

Tags: jquery, html, css

What is the best way to add current class to the .navimg divs (next to li) when their parent link is clicked?

HTML:

```
<div id="navbox">    
    <ul id="navigation">
        <li id="home"><a href="#">HOME</a></li>                               <div id="imghome" class="navimg current"></div>
        <li id="corp_gov"><a href="#">CORPORATE <br /> GOVERNANCE</a></li>    <div id="imggov" class="navimg"></div>
        <li id="board"><a href="#">BOARD &amp; <br /> DIRECTORS</a></li>      <div id="imgboard" class="navimg"></div>
        <li id="permit"><a href="#">PERMIT <br /> DETAILS</a></li>            <div id="imgpermit" class="navimg"></div>
        <li id="corp_dir"><a href="#">CORPORATE <br /> DIRECTORY</a></li>     <div id="imgdir" class="navimg"></div>
    <li id="contact"><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>                             <div id="imgcontact" class="navimg"></div>
</ul>
</div>
```

I have tried to use this that I found in another Question on here using a bunch of variations but it isn't working right now:

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {          
    $("#navbox ul li a").click(function(e) {
        $(".current").removeClass("current");
        $(this).nextAll("div.navimg").first().addClass("current");
});
```

Is this the best method to use or what would you suggest?
Do I have to make a new function for each link or can one like this work for all of them?

I tried this as well to try and target each link specifically but that didn't work either:

```
$("li#home a").click(function(e) {
    $(".current").removeClass("current");
    $("#imghome").addClass("current");
```

Thanks everyone

EDIT:
I made a jsFiddle showing what is going on:
http://jsfiddle.net/Amp3rsand/vGTpW/2/

Comment: share html for `navimg`

Comment: @ArunPJohny It's there. Scroll right

Comment: Should have made that more apparent or moved the div under the li I suppose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modifed the HTML to include the imgnav inside the li.

Check the Fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/ScQtx/

jQuery:

```
var $allNavImgs = $('.navimg');
$("a","#navbox").on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $allNavImgs.removeClass('current');
    $(this).siblings().filter('.navimg').addClass('current');
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="navbox">    
    <ul id="navigation">
        <li id="home">
            <a href="#">HOME</a>
            <div id="imghome" class="navimg current"></div>
        </li>                               
        <li id="corp_gov">
            <a href="#">CORPORATE <br /> GOVERNANCE</a>
            <div id="imggov" class="navimg"></div>
        </li>    
        <li id="board">
            <a href="#">BOARD &amp; <br /> DIRECTORS</a>
            <div id="imgboard" class="navimg"></div>
        </li>      
        <li id="permit">
            <a href="#">PERMIT <br /> DETAILS</a>
            <div id="imgpermit" class="navimg"></div>
        </li>            
        <li id="corp_dir">
            <a href="#">CORPORATE <br /> DIRECTORY</a>
            <div id="imgdir" class="navimg"></div>
        </li>     
    <li id="contact">
        <a href="#">CONTACT</a>
        <div id="imgcontact" class="navimg"></div>
    </li>                             
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: less is more when it comes to selector performance in jQuery.  This selector applies a single listener on the navbox, and listens for when a LINK is clicked.  Since the first selection is an ID it is extremely fast. This will also work it you want to add more items to the DOM later.

Comment: Thanks for the help but I can't make your suggestion work.
Can I ask why you moved the navimg inside the li? Your jsfiddle works great but it seems like moving navimg has broken the hover animations. I'm referencing it wrong but I can't see where.
I forked my jsfiddle with your suggestion and you can see what I mean if you uncomment your html example: http://jsfiddle.net/Amp3rsand/8b8BX/1/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8b8BX/3/   you didn't have jQuery enabled.  Looks to be working.

Comment: I read you issue wrong.  Here is the working fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/8b8BX/4/  Since I moved the NAVIMGs inside the LIs the CSS Selector changed.  You don't need the + symbol since you are no longer selecting the item after... you are selecting a descendant.  #home:hover #imghome

Answer (score 3):

You forget to add `.parent()`

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z5rcj/)**

```
$("#navbox ul li a").click(function (e) {
   $(".current").removeClass("current");
   $(this).parent().next("div.navimg").addClass("current");
});
```

Comment: Hmm that makes sense but it still isn't doing it for me. Check out my jsfiddle showing sort of what I'm trying to do: http://jsfiddle.net/Amp3rsand/vGTpW/2/

Comment: What is  the problem?

Comment: I'm not sure really. Clicking simply isn't doing anything. I'm trying what Daniel suggested right now, it seems logical so fingers crossed

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish is my question? I updated **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vGTpW/3/)**

Comment: If you look at the jsFiddle the blue squares will be used as the indicator for the current page once styled. It is all working now after combining a bunch of suggestions together.